# Break string into two parts on basis of the field width in crystal report

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am currently working on desktop application. I want to convert currency into words. I did it successfully.Now I have two field objects of crystal report. one with width 4000 twips and another with width 5000 twips. 
 But now I want to break this words in two parts such that first part fits in first object (400 twips) and remaining in second.

Ex. Currency into words-Four Thousand Five Hundred Fifty Only

```
First Object 
----------------------------
|Four Thousand Five Hundred|
----------------------------

Second Object
----------------------------------------
|Fifty Only                             |
-----------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0):

The only (somewhat-hacky) way that I know of to do this is to 1. Use a fixed-width font and 2. Figure out how many characters fit in the objects.

So, in your example, "Four Thousand Five Hundred" goes to the very end of the 4000 twip field so you know that 26 characters fit in that field. You'd then be able to chop off the first words that fit in 26 characters. Something like:

```
local stringvar input := {table.yourString};
//local stringvar input := "Four Thousand Five Hundred Fifty";
local stringvar array inputSplit := split(input," ");
local numbervar charCount := 0;
local numbervar i;

//output strings
global firstString := "";
global secondString := "";

//for each word in the input...
for i := 1 to ubound(inputSplit) do
  (charCount := charCount + length(inputSplit[i]) + 1;
   if charCount <= 27 then firstString := firstString + " " + inputSplit[i]
     else secondString := secondString + " " + inputSplit[i]);

//remove leading whitespace
firstString := trim(firstString);
secondString := trim(secondString);
```